# Mistakenly named migration - rake db:migrate rejected

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, database-migration

This has happened to me a few times, the following is just an example of the table name and some params:

I mistakenly name a table while adding details during a migration `rails g migration AddOwnerToRestaurant owner:string`and run `rake db:migrate`;

I destroy the migration `rails destroy migration AddOwnerToRestaurant owner:string`and run `rake db:rollback`;

then I rename the table correctly with the same details `rails g migration AddOwnerToRestaurants` and `rake db:migrate`...

I keep getting the error message

```
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

SQLite3::SQLException: duplicate column name: owner
```

Why doesn't the owner column delete with the first `rails destroy` command?  I can't migrate the new addition to the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rollback` doesn't know what your database used to look like.  It looks at the last migrate and undoes whatever is in your `change` method, assuming you only call methods that rails knows how to reverse ([list](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#using-the-change-method)).

When you delete the migration first with `rails destroy migration`, rollback can't do it's job the way you want it to.  Don't delete the migration, instead roll it back and rewrite it, then migrate up again.

Also, you don't need the column information when destroying a migration

Answer (score 0):

Since you deleted the file, then do:

```
rake db:migrate:status
```

It will show you the ID of the missing file. So you can recreate it and then rollback.

```
rake db:rollback STEP=n
```

With 'n' being the number of rollbacks from last migration.

Don't destroy it again. Instead, create new migrations that undo the mistake of the previous ones.

Comment: Migrations are run in a transaction.  If it fails, assuming your DB supports transactions, which OP's does, it will automatically be cleaned up

Comment: Oops. Didn't realize it. Thanks. Changed my answer.